# Stuck on "tracker-store" during search file CentOS 7

Tags: centos, vmware, freeze

I run a CentOS 7 on VM11.The problem is whenever I type a letter on the file browser to activate search function that particular GUI stuck (but not other ones). Then I have to use Ctrl+Alt+F2 the kill the PID called"tracker-store" to unstuck the program.Any idea what might cause this issue?should I reinstall anything?

I also realize the hard drive reading speed is a bit slow under VM environment but still acceptable.[image]

Here you can see the cpu usage is not very high either does it consume much memory.[image]

Comment: It has something to do with multiprocessor,when I switch back to single processor the problem disappears.However if I select two cpu the program dont know how to distribute task among them and both cpu are on low usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is how I disable the gnome indexer.The issues seems disappeared. I don,t know how it worked and still wish someone can come up with an answer with more explanation.

In terminal:

```
[yourname@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install tracker-preferences
Password: ****
```

In desktop gui:
  click search and indexing [image]
  uncheck everything and delete every thing[image]

Test and works!

Answer (score -1):

It's​ a Gnome 3 indexer...

You can disable it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/194051)

Comment: @Kusalananda et al. How is this not an answer? The question was "Any idea what might cause this issue?", the answer is "It's a Gnome 3 indexer"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Sorry, but what I miss from this answer is 1) Why is the indexer causing this issue? 2) How does one disable it?  If it is known that a specific process is causing an issue, and that it's resolved by killing it, the answer should ideally contain an explanation of the cause and a description of how to properly fix it.

Comment: Sure, it would be nice if “[german](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/232027/german)” explained why the indexer is causing this issue, ideally with citations.  And, since this post doesn’t describe how the user can disable the indexer, it’s a poor answer.  And there’s the bottom line: ***it is a poor answer***; therefore, it is an answer.  See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/195817) and [You’re doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1672723) (I hope you like apples).

Comment: Ok this is an answer but not an elaborated answer.And since there is no other answer to compare with its still better than nothing.Yes it seems like has something to do with indexer but I wouldn't know how to disable it unless someone tell me.And I would like very much fixing it and explain the detail mechanism rather than disable it. The indexer is there for its purpose so it is the multiprocessor. If you knew more about it please share.